# prompt will not recognize winning condition in hangman game

Tags: javascript, debugging, prompt

After much trial and error, I have finally almost completed my basic, prompt-only, solo hangman project, but i have run into an issue. I have set a condition for which i have a variable recognize how many correct "hits" are in the word, and if the "hits" match the length of the word, "YOU WIN!" is supposed to be displayed. However, i cant seem to get the program to actually do this. I've tried multiple different ways of doing this, but the "guess a letter" prompt still shows up, after the victory conditions have been met. My "Game Over" prompt works just fine, which is confusing to me.

```
`var secretWords = ["hang", "golf", "many", "barn", "math"];
 var chosenWord = secretWords[Math.floor(Math.random()*secretWords.length)];
 var guesses = 8;
 console.log(chosenWord);
 var letters = chosenWord.length;
 var counter = 0;
 var gameOver = guesses === 0;
 console.log(guesses);
 console.log(counter);


while(guesses !== 0){
const guess = prompt("GUESS A LETTER")
let guessLowerCase = guess.toLowerCase();
let isGuessedLetterInWord = chosenWord.includes(guessLowerCase);
if (isGuessedLetterInWord) {
  alert('nice'); counter ++;

 }  if(isGuessedLetterInWord == 0)  {
alert('wrong'); guesses --;



}
else if (isGuessedLetterInWord == null){
break;
}
}


while(guesses == 0){
 alert('GAME OVER'); break;
 }

counter += chosenWord.length;
while(counter == chosenWord.length){
alert("YOU WIN!!")
}`
```

Comment: One oddity is that you set isGuessedLetterInWord to a boolean value and then check it against an int value in a following if block and then check it against null immediately after. You are using the "==" and not the "===" so this could work, but it is a little strange.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the counter check at the end of the `while (guesses !== 0) {` block - if outside, it won't be part of the game loop. You also can't increment `counter` unconditionally - some words have more than 2 of the same letter, eg `foo`, in which case you'd want a guess of `o` to fill in both `o`s, not just one. In the spirit of hangman, alert the filled in letters to the user so they can see what they're missing:

```js
var secretWords = ["hang", "golf", "many", "barn", "math"];
var chosenWord = secretWords[Math.floor(Math.random() * secretWords.length)];
let printedWord = chosenWord.replace(/./g, '-');
var guesses = 8;
console.log(chosenWord);
while (true) {
  const guess = prompt(`Guess a letter, ${guesses} remaining`);
  if (!guess) break;
  const guessLowerCase = guess.toLowerCase();
  let found = false;
  for (let i = 0; i < chosenWord.length; i++) {
    if (chosenWord[i] === guessLowerCase) {
      printedWord = printedWord.slice(0, i) + guessLowerCase + printedWord.slice(i + 1);
      found = true;
    }
  }
  alert(printedWord);
  if (!printedWord.includes('-')) {
    alert('You Win');
    break;
  }
  if (!found) guesses--;
  if (guesses === 0) {
    alert('You Lose');
    break;
  }
}
```